# is there way to generate web enabled rendition for png in aem?

Tags: aem, dam

I have custom workflow which generates web enabled renditions for images,even for png also it generates like cq5.web.1024.666.png ,but i want it like cq5.web.1024.666.jpg. I am not sure its proper way or not.

If it is PNG image then, are we suppose to use only thumbnail rendition?

Comment: compare to PNG jpg is lossy conversion, please make sure it is what you need.., if yes there are a lot of converter and codes available for that..

Answer (score 0):

Simply configure the Web Enabled Rendition Process step in the Update Dam Asset workflow to be something like:

dimension:1280:1280,mimetype:image/jpeg,quality:90,skip:application/pdf,skip:audio/mpeg,skip:video/(.*)

Adjust values as appropriate.